# How to create multiple column in an one row UITableViewCell in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

How to Create multiple column in an one row.
Like this image!. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEuO0hUUUAARX_L.png !

Comment: why not use a collection view?

Comment: You can use UICollectionView otherwise you need to write logic to populate the row with required data, by giving proper space for each value.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1 , http://www.raywenderlich.com/78551/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-2 Follow these tutorials to learn collection view in swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use gridview for your requirement like [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView#readme) or  [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView)

Check below sample code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"gridCell";
    UITableViewCell *gridCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(gridCell == nil)
    {
        gridCell =  [[[UITableViewCellalloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        gridCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        gridCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSArray* items = [_grids objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    int imageIndex = 0;
    int yOffset = 0;

    while (imageIndex < items.count)
    {
        int yPos = 4 + yOffset * 74;

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            CGRect  rect = CGRectMake((18 + i * 80), yPos, 40, 40);

            UIImageView* imageView = [self gridImageRect:rect forImage:[items objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
            [gridCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];

            rect = CGRectMake(((80 * i)-4), (yPos+44), 80, 12);

            UILabel* label = [self descriptionOfImage:imageIndex inRect:rect];
            [gridCell.contentView addSubview:label];
            [label release];

            ++imageIndex;

        }

        ++yOffset;
    }

    return gridCell;
}
```

Comment: Need Swift Code, no need Objective-C Code